# why these two codes give different outputs

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Given the following codes:

**code1:**

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
        Screen1Controller controller = loader.getController();
        if(controller == null)
            System.out.println(" controller is null");
            else System.out.println("controller is not null");
```

**output:**
  *controller is null*

**code2:**

```
        FXMLLoader loader =  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
//        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
        Screen1Controller controller = loader.getController();
        if(controller == null)
            System.out.println(" controller is null");
            else System.out.println("controller is not null");
```

**output:**
  *controller is not null*

I thought that they will give the same result? Is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line

```
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen1.fxml"));
```

you call `getResource(URL)`. That method is static, so it doesn't change any instance of `FXMLLoader` (and particulary doesn't create controller inside your `loader`).

Perhaps you wanted to call `getResource(InputStream)`, which isn't static. If so, you should change your code to:

```
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Screen1.fxml"));
```